# Coldfusion 8 -> 9 update, functions no longer working

Tags: variables, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8, application.cfc

HELP!!

Just migrating a site from one server to another, the coldfusion version is changing from cf8 to cf9 [linux/centos]

this code used to work before:

```
cfinclude('../SQL/contact.sql.cfc');
form.phone = unFormatPhone(form.phone);
contactID = InsertContact(form);
```

In the included file is:

```
<cfcomponent output="false" >
<!--- -------------------------------- insert -------------------------------- --->
<cffunction name="InsertContact" returntype="numeric" output="false" access="public" >
```

now I get an error when browsing the pages:

```
Variable INSERTCONTACT is undefined.


The error occurred in /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.com/httpdocs/Assets/XHTML/buy-my-car.cfm: line 54
Called from /var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/httpdocs/Application.cfc: line 232
Called from /var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/httpdocs/Application.cfc: line 230
Called from /var/www/vhosts/newride.ca/httpdocs/Application.cfc: line 162
52 :            cfinclude('../SQL/contact.sql.cfc');
53 :            form.phone = unFormatPhone(form.phone);
54 :            contactID = InsertContact(form);
55 :            
56 :            //insert vehicle with app id
```

What is going on here? the included file is being found, is there some difference between the two versions that is causing this?

Comment: Can you pls clarify what you're doing INCLUDING a CFC?  I'm surprised that worked on any version of CF.

Comment: I guess he is using the cfc as a collection of tools.  It does work even on Railo strange as that may seam.

Comment: Interesting.  I really didn't think that was allowed.

Comment: Hi @Paul, yeah I get that. I rather more meant "why?".  I mean as opposed to using the CFC as it's intended.

Comment: It's not my code, looks like the cfc's are mostly invoked but sometimes [like above] are included when someone got lazy.  I've moved a couple of these where all you have to do is comment out the cfcomponent tag in the cfc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure its being included?  try:

```
include "../SQL/contact.sql.cfc";
form.phone = unFormatPhone(form.phone);
contactID = InsertContact(form);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'll say first off that I've only worked with CF9, so I can't comment on what you used to be able to do in CF8.  But, in CF9 I'm pretty sure you cant use a CFC that way.  The closest thing to what you're doing would be transient invocation using `<cfinvoke>`.  See here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7db3.html

But, also look at instantiating the cfc as an object and then calling methods on that object.  I like doing it that way as it reminds me of other languages such as Java and C#.